# Unable to run cucumber tests from command line

Tags: jenkins, cucumber, junit, maven, pom

I know this is the most common question but sorry I am posting this again as I tried all the solutions but couldn't solve the issue,

Problem: I am unable to run my cucumber tests through maven and Jenkins

Command i am using:

```
mvn clean -Dcucumber.options="--@tags @tags" -Dbrowser=REMOTE_CHROME -Denv={env}
```

1. feature files in `src/test/resources`
2. steps and Runner in `src/test/java`

not sure what to include in pom - I have `info.cukes`, can some one please help if hooks is really needed to run the tests through maven or Jenkins

or is it problem with the project structure

Runner:

```
 @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
 @CucumberOptions(
    plugin = {"pretty"},
    features = {"src/test/resources"},
    tags = {"@regression,@add-documents,@add-payment"})
  public class RunRegressionTest {

   }
```

maven Result:

```
   Running com.loveholidays.travelthing.RunRegressionTest
```

Configuring TestNG with: org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf.TestNG652Configurator@2a098129
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.657 sec

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS

Comment: Please add the error message that you're getting. Would help in debugging.

Comment: I dont see any error message it says build success

Answer (score 1):

`mvn clean` means you're executing the clean phase of maven which would not run any tests. You should probably try test or verify, e.g. `mvn clean verify`. More to read: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html

Comment: I tried with mvn clean verify and mvn clean test it didnt help, it says build success with tests run: 0

Comment: What other errors/warnings you are getting after 'mvn clean verify'.

Comment: i dont get any warning or error, i see build is success and tests run are 0

Comment: @LaxmiMaddali have you added the dependency of Maven and Maven surefire plugin in your pom.xml. Check that if those are not included add in pom.xml and save then retry it. You can also refer this link for the configuration example: https://www.guru99.com/maven-jenkins-with-selenium-complete-tutorial.html